# Save List<String> to File with location choose window from server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

Right now, I have a method that goes to database, get some data, write it to a file and write it to disk. Here's the code:

```
public void Index()
{
    List<Log> logList = database.GetLog().OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList();
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    string date = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

    foreach (var item in logList)
    {
            // Adds the information on the person
            lines.Add(String.Format("Date-{0}", item.LogDate));
            lines.Add(String.Format("Id-{0}", item.Id));
            lines.Add(String.Format("Message-{0}", item.Message));
            lines.Add(String.Format("StackTrace-{0}", item.StackTrace));
            lines.Add(String.Format("TargetSite-{0}", item.TargetSite));
            lines.Add(String.Format("Source-{0}", item.Source));
            lines.Add(String.Format("InnerException-{0}", item.InnerException));
            lines.Add(String.Format("HResult-{0}", item.HResult));
            lines.Add(String.Format("HelpLink-{0}", item.HelpLink));
            lines.Add(String.Format("Type-{0}", item.Type));
            lines.Add("----------------------------------------");
    }

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\report"+date+".txt", lines);
}
```

Now I want to prompt the user to choose the save location. The application will be on the server, so I can't use SaveFileDialog right? It's seems so simple and I'm here for a couple of hours and I can't find a solution.

Comment: Collect that information via some UI beforehand and then pass as a parameter or object property?

Comment: You need to create a view with a form, that posts back to the controller with the path of where the file should save. If you need the user to be able to select where the file should go, then you are going to have to create a folder viewer in the view (though most likely there is already a lot code examples on how to do that part).

Comment: Can you do this? Won't you run into security issues if the user selects a protected file location?

Comment: "You want to prompt the user where to save, but not through SaveFileDialog", how about save the file on a shared folder then show that shared folder(Read-only) so user may copy it somewhere else? this is confusing haha

Comment: Do you want to download and save the file in the client machine?